Get USD file start frame number in Python?
USD file stage may have an arbitrary start frame. Is there a way to access that information from Python?
There is a (bpy.context.active_object.modifiers[0]).cache_file object, but it seems not to store USD stage start frame information, which would be needed to set the cache file offset frame to match the actual timeline.
For example - adding a simulation asset USD with stage start @frame 173, to the scene @frame 3320 is quite cumbersome - the user has to scrub through unknown length of frame offset to find the data. So I'm trying to make a Match Current Frame function.
